# Using experimental inspector feature with the GCP debug-agent

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-debugger

This section of the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/debug-agent#experimental-features (for nodejs) shows that it's available, but when looking in the Cloud Console UI, there is nothing about the inspector feature. How does one use this feature, maybe via `kubectl proxy` interface or like a cluster ip and the inspector port?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't see it in the *Debug* UI?

Comment: Exactly. At least I'm not even sure what I should see. It looks the same with it enabled and disabled.

Comment: Can you post your lambda? Simplify the lambda to remove anything that is not relevant to the issue ; for example you'll probably just have a print statement and the wrapper code for debugger integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read from the documentation: "The Stackdriver Debugger includes experimental support for the new V8 Inspector Protocol"

So there is not a inspector UI. It just enables a diferent protocol to debug.

Here[1] is the official documentation, and here[2] the link to access the Stackdriver Debug web UI.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/debugger/
[2] https://console.cloud.google.com/debug?_ga=2.189317867.-1503149812.1525863938

Comment: So is it internal only? Using the standard debug UI but working with the protocol instead of some internal Google solution?

Comment: I do not understand your question. It only will change the protocol that it uses. The functionalities will be the same. You can read[1] here information about the protocol. [1] https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/v8/

Comment: Got it. I thought it enabled the use of chrome devtools to debug my app :) but that is a dream haha.